# Print the output of matched strings from separate lines to an output file, on the same line

Tags: awk, grep

I have the following details in the `input.txt` file and I need to print the output like below.

`input.txt`:

```
Name         = testserver1.net
IP-Address   = 10.0.0.1
OStype       = XPClient
Name         = testserver2.net
IP-Address   = 10.0.0.2
OStype       = Server2003
```

Output should be like this:

```
testserver1.net 10.0.0.1
testserver2.net 10.0.0.2
```

So far i have done like this:

```
 awk '/Name/ {print $3}; /IP/ {print $3}' input.txt
```

But, I want to print the output like above, in row format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '/Name/ {printf "%s ",$3}; /IP/ {print $3}' file
testserver1.net 10.0.0.1
testserver2.net 10.0.0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$  awk '/Name/{name=$3} /IP/{print name, $3}' input.txt
testserver1.net 10.0.0.1
testserver2.net 10.0.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
$ sed -n '/testserver/{N;s/.*\(testserver\).*= \(.*\)$/\1 \2/p}' input.txt
testserver 10.0.0.1
testserver 10.0.0.2
```

which does in detail (`-n` prevents printing unless explicitly instructed to):

```
/testserver/ {        # If we match 'testserver'
    N                 # Load the next line into pattern space

    # Substitution: only keep 'testserver' and what's after '=' on the next line
    # 'p' flag prints pattern space after substitution
    s/.*\(testserver\).*= \(.*\)$/\1 \2/p
}
```